# Is there a way to make a collapsible sidebar using ReactJs

Tags: reactjs

I am currently making a dashboard using ReactJs. The navbar is located on the left side of the page and I am attempting to make it collapsible. I have managed to add a collapsible component using the react-collapsible module, however, this collapses upwards. I want the navbar to collapse into the left side of the screen and the content to move across when the navbar is not open. I am struggling to find much documentation on the react-collapsible module based on this.

Current Code:

```
<Collapsible trigger={["", <BsChevronDown />]}>
   <Sidebar /> 
</Collapsible>
```

CSS:

```
.Collapsible__trigger {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    font-size: 20px;
    color: rgb(187, 186, 186);
    position: relative;
    left: 55px
}

.Collapsible__trigger.is-open svg {
    transform: rotate(180deg);
}
```

Ultimately, I would like the navbar to collapse from right to left instead of upwards. If anyone has any idea on how to do this using react-collapsible or could suggest a better way that would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is that all the CSS? I would expect to see more in regards to the animations etc. However, for me, this looks like a case of "wrong tool for the job".  react-collapsible is for accordions and you want a sidebar. I would strongly suggest you adopt a comprehensive and consistent design system library like Chakra (which is my personal favourite). https://chakra-ui.com/docs/components/drawer should do the trick.

Comment: MUI has a pretty good drawer side bar too

Comment: I'll add if you already have a DS and you're wanting only the collapse animation https://github.com/DimitryDushkin/sliding-pane looks appropriate

Comment: **Collapsible** is a wrong word for a thing that you are trying to do because it's associated with a different type of UI component. Also, you don't need a library to do this. Just do this like in vanilla js.